# Asp Classic and IIS 6.0 : I'm looking for a "max upload size" variable?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I'm working with IIS 6.0 and ASP CLASSIC.

My point is to upload file (PDF) and I know there's a limit (200kb by default) but I want to know the max limit of uploaded files (the limit of the server) with a server variable maybe or a conf. file which I can access with asp. I don't want to write the limit in octets directly in my code. 
Is that possible ?

I checked IIS Server Variables on the Microsoft Website and found nothing.
Maybe there is no solution to this problem but if someone got one, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look of this http://www.banmanpro.com/support2/file_upload_limits.asp

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually, I try to read the metadata.xml with a few lines of asp to get the value of  **AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed**. But I thing that is not possible ...

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the size of the setting "Maximum Requesting Entity Body Limit" under ASP > Limits Properties.